# How to discover the underlying Implementation Type of a decorated instance when calling GetAllInstances?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

I have this code:

```
using (container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    RenderWord instruction = new RenderWord();
    var instances = container.GetAllInstances<IInstructionHandler<RenderWord>>();
    var firstInstance = result.First();
}
```

`instances` is of type `IEnumerable<IInstructionHandler<RenderWord>>`

`firstInstance` is of type `IInstructionHandler<RenderWord>` that in reality is an instance of a decorator that decorates another decorator that decorates another decorator ...

At runtime the actual class `instances` is of type `ContainerControlledCollection<IInstructionHandler<RenderWord>>` and this `ContainerControlledCollection` class holds a very useful piece of information - the underlying `ImplementationType`.

Is there any way for me to get to the `ContainerControlledCollection` or the `producers[0].Value.ImplementationType` at runtime because I’d really like to be able to discover the base implementation type underneath the chain of decorators.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: @Steven I'm trying out a POC where all sorts of `Handler`s can be plugged in at runtime and can be controlled/co-ordinated with database configuration - so just because a `Handler` *can* be applied does not mean that it always *will* be applied. With all the benefits of the standard in-built decorators (tracing etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @atomaras might have a good point about your abstraction, although I think it would be fine when you only use this information inside your Composition Root, since your Composition Root is already aware of every implementation in the system.

I think there are a few ways to get to this information:

1. Use the `DecoratorPredicateContext` information that is supplied to the `RegisterDecorator` extension method:

   ```
   var typeMapping = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();

   container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IInstructionHandler<>), typeof(FakeDecorator<>), c =>
   {
       typeMapping[c.ServiceType]  = c.ImplementationType;
       // or perhaps even use c.AppliedDecorators property to see which decorators 
       // are applied.

       // return false to prevent the decorator from being applied.
       return false;
   });
   ```

   You can make a fake registration that Simple Injector will call for every `IInstructionHandler<T>` in the system, but you prevent it from being applied by supplying a predicate that will always return `false`. You can use the info supplied by Simple Injector in the `DecoratorPredicateContext` to find out what the actual ImplementationType is.

Alternatively, you can inject an `DecoratorContext` instance (v2.6 and up) into the top most decorator (as explained [here](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#using-contextual-information-inside-decorators)). The `DecoratorContext` contains the same information as the `DecoratorPredicateContext` does, but this object will automatically be injected by Simple Injector into a decorator that depends on. It allows you to make the decision inside a decorator, which might be very convenient in your case.

2. Add an an `IDecorator` abstraction to the system to allow traversing the decorator chain.

   By letting each decorator implement a `IDecorator` interface that allows access to the decoratee (just as done [here](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/discussions/447100)) you can traverse the decorator chain and find the actual implementation type:

   ```
   public interface IDecorator
   {
       object Decoratee { get; }
   }

   public static class DecoratorHelpers
   {
       public static IEnumerable<object> GetDecoratorChain(IDecorator decorator)
       {
           while (decorator != null)
           {
               yield return decorator;

               decorator = decorator.Decoratee as IDecorator;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   You can implement your decorators with this interface as follows:

   ```
   public class SomeDecorator<T> : IInstructionHandler<T>, IDecorator
   {
       private readonly IInstructionHandler<T> decoratee;

       public SomeDecorator(IInstructionHandler<T> decoratee)
       {
           this.decoratee = decoratee;
       }

       object IDecorator.Decoratee { get { return this.decoratee; } }
   }
   ```

   When you implemented this interface on all your decorators, you will be able to do this:

   ```
    var implementationTypes =
        from handler in container.GetAllInstances<IInstructionHandler<RenderWord>>()
        let mostInnerDecorator =
            DecoratorHelpers.GetDecoratorChain(handler as IDecorator).LastOrDefault()
        let implementation = mostInnerDecorator != null ? mostInnerDecorator.Decoratee : handler
        select implementation.GetType()
   ```
3. Register a list of `Registration` instances in one of the `RegisterAll` overloads, since the `Registration` object knows about the actual implemenation type.
4. But instead of point 3, you might as well use the list of implemenation types that you used to create those registrations:

   ```
   typeMapping[serviceType] = implementationTypes;
   container.RegisterAll(serviceType, implementationTypes);
   ```

   Simple Injector will resolve the registered implementations always in the same order as they are registered (this is guaranteed). So when you resolve a collection of things, you will already have the list of implementations that is layed out in the same order.

Comment: Option 1 is the feature that I am looking for. I only need this information in one place (the composition root) and this was the driver for finding a solution that did not require an almost redundant interface & property on the `IHandler` decorators.

Comment: Simple Injector always applies decorators in the sequence *last in first out*. Are the collections that get registered using `RegisterAll` returned in the sequence *first in first out*?

Comment: @qujck: if you do `container.RegisterAll<T>(t1, t2, t3, t4)`, a call to `container.GetAllInstances<T>()` will *always* return the list in the order `t1, t2, t3, t4`. That's by design and this order will **never** change.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you just check the type of the firstInstance? Wouldn't that give you the actual implementation type? 
I have to say though that the fact that you need to know the implementation type is a good indication of problems with your abstraction.

Comment: The type of all the instances will be same decorator e.g. `ExceptionDecorator` wrapping `TransactionDecorator` wrapping `TraceDecorator`. On the surface I may be violating some of the numerous **best practices** but for this particular solution I need a combination of plug-ins and runtime configurability.

Comment: Although i still don't see the need for doing so, you could enhance your Handler interface to expose the wrapped/decorated Handler as a property and create a very specialized method that drills down the chain in a while loop to find the innermost handler type.

Comment: You're absolutely correct and that was my plan until I noticed that the implementation type I needed is so nearly available already. I can, for example, define an `IHandlerDecorator` to expose the underlying implementation detail through a property.